# Interplanetary sci-fi book featuring a ring with an illegal operating system

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking to identify a book that I read a long time ago and have not been able to remember.

It's interplanetary sci-fi. There is a lady with a ring, and the ring contains an illegal OS called Prime. Can't remember if she is the protagonist.

There is a scene where she kills a soldier by using the ring to override his armor neck port and let the blood out. Also there are soldiers who investigate a swamp and have 360 degrees eye helmets, very advanced tech.

Only other thing I can remember is that gamma ray sterilization of planets is a thing too.

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask them as separate questions.

Comment: The first one is Fallen Dragon by Peter F Hamilton.

Comment: Thanks timbp for that; also have edited question to be only about one book at a time.

Answer (score 3):

This book has been identified as [*Fallen Dragon*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45258.Fallen_Dragon) (2001) by Peter F. Hamilton, credit to @timbp.

From Goodreads:

> *Deploying invulnerable twenty-fifth-century soldiers called Skins,
>   Zantiu-Braun's corporate starships loot entire planets. But as the
>   Skins invade bucolic Thallspring, Z-B's strategy is about to go awry,
>   all because of: Sgt. Lawrence Newton, a dreamer whose twenty years as
>   a Skin have destroyed his hopes and desires; Denise Ebourn, a school
>   teacher and resistance leader whose guerrilla tactics rival those of
>   Che Guevara and George Washington and Simon Roderick, the director who
>   serves Z-B with a dedication that not even he himself can understand.
>   Grimly determined to steal, or protect, a mysterious treasure, the
>   three players engage in a private war that will explode into
>   unimaginable quests for personal grace...or galactic domination*

[image: Fallen Drgaon cover]